# Numbers that can be expressed as $ab + a + b$

Tags: integers

How many positive integers $n$ less than $100$ can be expressed in the form $ab + a + b,$ where $a,b$ are positive integers?

---

I wasn't quite sure how to approach this problem besides simply finding values for all the numbers or making a table, so is there a slicker solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $ab+a+b=(a+1)(b+1)-1$ so the numbers $n$ that can be expressed in that form are exactly those for which $n+1$ is not prime.